# show icon with p:commandLink

Tags: primefaces, icons, commandlink

How to show an icon with commandLink:

```
<p:commandLink 
         styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"
         action="#{bean.doSomething}"     >

         <h:outputText value="Add" />   
</p:commandLink>
```

The outputText (Add) is not visible. What is the right way for commandLink to support icon? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
<p:commandLink action="#{bean.doSomething}">
     <h:outputText value="Add" class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"/>   </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is a bit of a combination of the previous two answers, but it worked the best for me. Remove `styleClass`, but you don't need to use `graphicImage`.

Instead you can use the `<i class=""></i>` tag.

```
    <p:commandLink action="#{bean.doSomething}">
        <h:outputText value="Add"/><i class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></i>
    </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Awesome library with a lot of icons. This an example how o it has worked for me:

```
<!-- Delete Button -->
<p:commandLink style="padding: .3em 1em"
                      styleClass="fa fa-trash"      
                      process=":formDataTable:customers"                                       
                      update=":formDataTable:customers">
    <p:confirm header="Delete Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    <p:collector value="#{customer}" removeFrom="#{customersController.customers}" unique="true"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

In your case it would be like this:

```
<p:commandLink 
     styleClass="fa fa-user-plus"
     action="#{bean.doSomething}">
     <h:outputText value="Add" />   
</p:commandLink>
```

Just be sure to the the web.xml with primefaces.FONT_AWESOME to true like this:

```
<!-- web.xml -->
 <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

I hope it helps somebody else!

Answer (score -1):

You should remove `styleClass` and use a `graphicImage` with a text  :

```
<p:commandLink >
    <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/add.png" title="add"  >
        add
    </h:graphicImage>
</p:commandLink>
```